# Loop a simple command in CMD prompt from data list

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to run the following

```
dir *.EXT /b > EXT_list.txt
```

Where EXT = [tab,shp,ecw,pdf]

How can I do this?

From http://commandwindows.com/batchfiles-iterating.htm I can try the following

> for %%X in (file1 file2 file3) do command

I get

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\PowerCmd>for %%EXT in (tab shp ecw pdf) do (dir *.%%EXT /b > %%EXT_list.txt)
%%EXT was unexpected at this time.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`For` loop variables can only be one letter long (but they are case-sensitive, so you have 53 to work with, since you can also use `%%#`).

Also, you don't need the parentheses after `do` if it's only a one-liner.

`for %%A in (tab shp ecw pdf) do dir *.%%A >%%A_list.txt`